# Disable CreatedAt UpdatedAt DeletedAt Fields in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am usign GORM and I am mapping legacy tables.

By default GORM has this struct:

```
type Model struct {
        ID        uint      `gorm:"primarykey"`
        CreatedAt time.Time
        UpdatedAt time.Time
        DeletedAt DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

I don't have CreatedAt UpdatedAt DeletedAt fields in the legacy table, I need to avoid or disable this default structure.

I can't find a way to avoid these columns.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your model as an embedded struct:

```golang
type MyModel struct {
  gorm.Model
  StringField  string
  IntField uint
}
```

You can create it using the declarations you mentioned in `gorm.Model`:

```golang
type MyModel struct {
  ID           uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
  StringField  string
  IntField     uint
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid fields `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt` and `DeletedAt` by **not** specifying `gorm.Model` inside the struct.

You have to explicitly declare what these struct fields would look like in Gorm by adding `gorm:"column_name"` next to them.

Lets assume that your legacy table is called `features` and it has columns `name` and `description`. So your struct would be:

```
type Feature struct {
    Name        string `gorm:"column:name"`
    Description string `gorm:"column:description"`
}
```

Or, if this table is used for REST API in addition to ORM:

```
type Feature struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"column:description"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the timestamp tracking by setting autoUpdateTime tag to false, for example: [Source](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#CreatedAt)

```
  CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
  UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
```

Comment: I've tested it but if I migrate the table gorm create all this fields and I have a legacy table without this fields.

Comment: This can't be done because OP's struct doesn't have these fields.